# Creating an ArrayList of Arrays with predetermined length

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Essentially, I'm looking to create an ArrayList of Arrays of Notes:

```
   /**
   * Represents the entire musical score, with each index of the ArrayList representing each beat.
   * Each array of notes represent the notes that can play on a single beat (up to 120 notes, 12
   * notes over 10 octaves.
   */
  private List<Note[]> score;
  ...
  score = new ArrayList<>(8); // Initialize ArrayList with capacity of 8
```

The first (minor) problem I'm running into here is first that the ArrayList could end up being any size and may have to grow many times (which doubles the size each time it requires additional capacity), and the second (more important) problem is that I'm unable to set the length of the Arrays contained within the ArrayList to 120 as follows:

```
private List<Note[120]> score;
```

This brings me to the question of how I can initialize all of the Arrays that may or may not exist in the ArrayList (because we don't know when/if/how often the ArrayList size may change) to a size of 120, and, if that is not possible, whether or not there is potentially a better data structure to be used in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(8)` sets the initial capacity to 8, *not* the size to 8.

Comment: @Makoto - Noted, did not make the difference clear in my comment

Comment: _"if that is not possible (...)"_ - It's probably possible, although I'm not sure either. --- _"whether or not there is potentially a better data type to be used in this situation"_ - A chunk-based approach is probably more appropriate in this kind of situation; instead of allocating all this space, you should process in smaller chunks, if possible.

Comment: It is not possible to initialise just the intent. To be able to initialise list elements to any length you need to have a code somewhere that creates them. This is where you can also fix the length to 120. What you seem to want is sort of a default value for your list elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no data type for an array of length `120`, so you cannot have a `List<Note[120]>` or a `List<Note[]>` where every array is guaranteed to have length `120`. What you can do is make your own class:

```
public final class TenOctaves {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_NOTES = 120;

    private final Note[] notes = new Note[NUMBER_OF_NOTES];

    public void setNote(int position, Note note) {
         if (position < 0 || position >= NUMBER_OF_NOTES)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         notes[position] = note;
    }

    public Note getNote(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= NUMBER_OF_NOTES)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return notes[position];
    }
}
```

Then you could have a `List<TenOctaves>` instead.

Comment: I like this approach to it quite a lot - I'll toy with it a bit and see if I can come up with something. It does a better job of upkeeping the SOLID principles than my initial approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could do with subclassing `ArrayList` and implementing your own special `add` logic.

```
public class NoteList extends ArrayList<Note[]> {

    private final int SCORE_LENGTH = 120;
    private final int MAX_ELEMENTS = 8;

    @Override
    public boolean add(Note[] score) {
        return this.size() <= MAX_ELEMENTS && score.length == SCORE_LENGTH && super.add(score);
    }
}
```

You won't be able to add elements to the list if:

- the size of the list is larger than 8
- the length of the array you're going to add is not 120

Comment: I like this approach as well, but I opted to go with making my own class representing a single Beat with getNote() and setNote() methods to spread functionality a bit more appropriately. Thanks for the input